# How do I perform retries and adjust timeout settings with @azure/storage-blob v12 for Node/JS?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

In the v10 implementation of Azure blob storage I could implement a retry policy with something like:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var retryPolicy = new azure.RetryPolicyFilter();
retryPolicy.retryCount = 3;
retryPolicy.retryInterval = 3000;
retryPolicy.shouldRetry = function(statusCode, retryContext) {
  //
};
var blobService = azure.createBlobService().withFilter(retryPolicy);
```

How would I do the equivalent in version **v12**?
Also, how do I log information when a retry occurs and how can I adjust timeout settings?

Answer (score 0):

The `BlobClient` and derived classes have two constructors that accept a `StoragePipelineOptions` as seen in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobclient?view=azure-node-latest#constructors)

The [`StoragePipelineOptions` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/storagepipelineoptions?view=azure-node-latest) contains a [`retryOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/storageretryoptions?view=azure-node-latest) property you can use.

Comment: I've tried this but how do know when a retry occurred? Where I can inject logging?